# AWS Athena: SELECT access allowed after revoking all the permissions on AWS lake formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-lake-formation

I'm using AWSlake formation te manage the permissions needed to use Athena.

For one of the users i revoked all his permissions, so now he can't see the databases, tables in athena Catalog, but when he runs any request directly from the editor, it still work.

He's not a ldata ake formation administrator, and he has full access on athena.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the Athena service has permissions via a service-linked role (created by Lake Formation): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/service-linked-roles.html

Since the user has access to Athena, his requests are being executed by the Athena service (which still has access).